# Simple java code for Weather Reporting

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

My home work assignment is to figure out:

- What this code does
- What potential problems there are

Code

```
/// Enum
public enum Event {
    TORNADO, THUNDERSTORM, TSUNAMI, RAIN, SNOW, WIND, COLD, HEAT; 
    public final static String CRITICAL = "Critical";
    public final static String SEVERE = "Severe";
    public final static String MEDIUM = "Medium";
    public final static String LIGHT = "Light";

    private String severity;
    private String location;

    public void setSeverity(String severity) {
        this.severity = severity; 
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ":" + severity + " at " + location; 
    }
}

///Interface
public interface IEventListener {
    void eventReceived(Event event); 
}

///Class
public class EventPublisher implements IEventListener {
    Map<Event, Collection<IEventListener>> listeners = new HashMap<Event, Collection<IEventListener>>(); 

    @Override 
    public synchronized void eventReceived(Event event) {
        for (IEventListener listener : listeners.get(event)){ 
            listener.eventReceived(event); 
        }
    }

    public synchronized void register(IEventListener listener, Event event){
        Collection<IEventListener> list = listeners.get(event); 
        if (list == null) {
            list = new LinkedList<IEventListener>();
            listeners.put(event, list); 
        }
        list.add(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void deregister(IEventListener listener, Event event) {
        listeners.get(event).remove(listener); 
    }

    public String toString() {
        String ret = ""; 
        Iterator<Event> i = listeners.keySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Iterator<IEventListener> j = listeners.get(i.next()).iterator();
            while (j.hasNext()) {
                ret = ret + i.next() + "::" + j.next() + "\n"; 
            }
        }
        return ret; 
    }
}
```

I went through the code and figured out that this code tries to produce the weather report and classify the weather condition based on `eventReceived` (`Event` can be registered/deRegistered).

I however cannot see any problems with the code. My teacher insists that there are issues. Can anyone help me?

Comment: One of the best ways to find problems in a program is to run it.

Comment: `Event` should not be an `enum`

Comment: There is too much bad weather!

Comment: Is Tsunami a weather? I would say that's more of a natural disaster, like a forest fire or earthquake. If you have Tsunami, you can iclude all kinds of bad stuff... floods, volcano eruption, meteor shower, Armageddon...

Comment: ..Javascript, Windows ME, Toyota Yaris, Coors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Event` should not be an `enum`. Since its members are effectively singletons; by changing the e.g. severity of *one* `TORNADO`, you'd change the severity of *all* of them. You should have an enum for `EventType`, one for `Severity`, and an `Event` class that uses them.

Then, your map inside the event publisher will change...

Also, the `deregister` method could throw a null reference exception...